# No Active Recurring Contributions on civi record but stripe has the data. Is there a way to resend IPN?

Tags: civicontribute, stripe

Due to a webhook problem, we have a few recurring donations that are now being processed by Stripe, but are not being recorded in our CiviCRM contribution table.

Is there a way to resend an IPN, or manually adjust Stripe so future donations get recorded in CiviCRM?

We are interested in having future payments from these people recorded in civiCRM. We can manually enter the missed records. 
Is there a way to have next month's donations to get transferred back to CiviCRM from Stripe?

Should I be asking this question differently?

Comment: I think we may be building an extension that sets up a scheduled job for retrying these. PM if you want more detail. peter.davis@fuzion.co.nz and i can pass through to a colleague

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  In Stripe, go to **Developers menu » Events**.  Items with a pending webhook will have an icon next to them as indicated in the screenshot below: 
[image]

Scroll to the bottom of the page and click "Retry all webhooks".

I'm not sure how long you can retry for - with PayPal it's 30 days, not sure about Stripe.[image]